# ChartWrapper.getChart() returns null

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to implement clickable chart in dashboard. The user will be redirected to a different webpage based on the segment of pie chart clicked. However, the chartObject is NULL when i use getChart() in the ChartWrapper object. I have no problem pulling out DataTable from ChartWrapper.

I've tried to use 'ready' event before 'select' event in my code but still get NULL. Any advice?

You can try out the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hKj7g/26)

```
// Define a Pie chart 3
    pie3 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart3',
      'options': {
        //'width': 400,
        'height': 300,
        'legend': {'position':'right', 'textStyle': {fontSize: 9}},
        'title': 'Audit Type',
        'chartArea': {'left': 80, 'top': 30, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0, 'height':300, 'widith':200},
        'pieSliceText': 'value',
        'slices': {0: {color: '#9fbfdf'}, 1: {color: '#6699cc'}, 2: {color: '#3973ac'}, 3: {color: '#738b28'}, 4: {color: '#a4c639'}, 5: {color: '#bfd774'}},
        'fontSize': 11
      },
      // from the 'data' DataTable.
      'view': {'columns': [6]}
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(pie3, 'ready', onReady);

    // Create a dashboard
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
        // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
        // picker will drive both charts.
        bind([yearPicker, slider2, categoryPicker], [pie, pie2, pie3]).
        // Draw the entire dashboard.
        draw(data);

    function onReady() {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(pie3.getChart(), 'select', handler);
    }

    function handler() {
        chartObject = pie3.getChart().getSelection();
        alert(chartObject);
    }

   }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Comment: I made a fiddle based on your code, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/hKj7g/.  Could you update your post with the full javascript code or a jsfiddle link to an example demonstrating them problem?

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle with my full code. You may try to click the third piechart. It returns null.

Comment: What's the new jsfiddle link?

Comment: i updated your link.  jsfiddle.net/asgallant/hKj7g

Comment: When you click "update" or "fork", it creates a new URL for the fiddle with your changes.  If you go to my fiddle link, it won't have your changes.

Comment: ahhh.. i see. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/hKj7g/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you are only passing 1 column of data to each PieChart.  The PieCharts expect to have two columns of data: 1 string column for pie slice labels, and 1 number column for pie slice values.  You need to add a second column of data to each PieChart.

Aside from that, you need to move your chart code outside the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` handler and load version 1 of the API instead of 1.1 (unless you have a specific reason to load the release candidate version).  Generally, your code should be organized like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // do stuff on document ready
});
function drawVisualization () {
    // draw dashboard
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls'], callback: drawVisualization});
```

Comment: Each pie slice needs a value in order to chart it properly.  The value is given by the second column of data.  Your data has "Internal" and "External" audit types, but they don't have values.  What percent of the pie should "External" be?  How will the chart know that if you don't provide the data?

Comment: The chart does a count on my DataTable on the number of rows "External" appeared in the table. As you can see from the link, my PieChart is capable of displaying the total number of "external" events by only passing 1 column of data. I've tried your suggestion by passing 2 columns of data. It actually works now. I'll need to think of how i can reorganize the structure of my DataTable so that it doesn't affect my dashboard controls and integrity of the Pie Charts.

Comment: That isn't doing what you want.  Your data has 2 "External" audits and 1 "Internal", but the PieChart shows 1 of each.  You need to use a grouping function ([google.visualization.data.group](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group)) to get a count of each, and then display the charts based on the result of the group.  Since you are also hooking up controls, this becomes a bit more complex, as you have to regroup the data every time a control changes state.